# Google Mobile Backend Starter: Extending the Mobile Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine

In [Google's docs on "Extending the Mobile Backend"](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend), there is supposed to be an explanation on how to customize the Google App Engine app that is provided with the Mobile Backend Starter. The approach is to modify its sourcecode and deploy that to Google App Engine.

However, the text refers to the sourcecode of the sample Android client, not of the Google App Engine app, which I guess is just wrong. In the README.md of the sample Android client, though, there is an unused footnote pointing to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java, which seems to be the correct sourcecode.

My questions now are:

1. Who can I tell that there is a mistake in the docs?
2. Does [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend) really reflect the latest version of the mobile backend that gets deployed when I hit the button as described in the docs on [Deploy Backend](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend)?
3. When I modify the backend, I effectively fork the sourcecode. Will future developments be reflected in Github so I can merge them into my modified app?

Comment: Hi @jfrantzius, I'm getting the same problems. Some google pages have a send feedback button, try that. Their support for these android-cloud integrations really need to be much more improved.

Comment: may be this one? - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java ...it says but: The mobile backend starter sample application is no longer supported. If you are looking for an easy way to connect your mobile app to Google Cloud Platform, we recommend you check out Cloud Endpoints. If you are already using the mobile backend starter your code will continue to work and no modifications are necessary at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend

(SO THERE IS NO WAY.... as the "Extending the Mobile Backend"... "Setup Instructions" tells you to use "Open Android SDK Manager and choose Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library" -> no longer available.

next is to use: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/